# performance penalty of checking for debugger.IsAttached

Tags: .net, vb.net

Using this exception handling pattern is convenient when debugging something complex.  Is there a performance penalty or any other reason not to leave the debugger check in production code?

```
try
    'logic goes here
Catch ex As Exception
    if (Debugger.IsAttached) then Debugger.Break()
    'log exception or handle as appropriate here
End Try
```

Comment: I don't have explicit knowledge about this, but as the check only happens when there is an exception it shouldn't be a big issue.. However, if the code in the try block is badly written and throws exceptions all the time, then there may well be an issue. the code `(Debugger.IsAttached)` suggests this might be a possibility because there is no need to have brackets at each end. `Try..Catch..End Try` should only be used to deal with "exceptional" circumstances that can't be coded for. Not as a substitute for lazy coding.

Comment: As a side note, you can use the `#if DEBUG` compile-time constant if you are worried.  Then just compile in Release mode for prod.

Answer (score 1):

After using this pattern for a while I can say there are no significant performance penalties.  I began using it when working with a legacy app that had a very tall inheritance tree (more then 10 levels of descendants) and it was very difficult to find where an exception was thrown.  This pattern makes it easier to debug errors because they are detected closer to the source, but more difficult because exceptions are detected at every higher level also.

After using this for a while, I would not recommend it.